# What about these cellphone questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, question-quality

Sorry to bother you again. After [pointing out some inconsistencies](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/to-park-for-free-or-not-to-park-for-free), I found the following questions, quite close to each other on the main page. They are about cellphones:

[Usable cell phone network in Montenegro Zabljak area for calls and data](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/usable-cell-phone-network-in-montenegro-zabljak-area-for-calls-and-data)

[What are the options for a prepaid SIM card in Germany?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/what-are-the-options-for-a-prepaid-sim-card-in-berlin)

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17298/cell-phone-in-california

Basically they ask for the same thing. They only differ by the location.

The voting patterns are again eclectic. Two are upvoted, and a third one is downvoted and closed. Are some users being mobbed?  Or are some users more equal than other users?

Answer (score 4):

The users are not getting mobbed and the issue is not with the user but with the question.

- [Usable cell phone network in Montenegro Zabljak area for calls and data](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/usable-cell-phone-network-in-montenegro-zabljak-area-for-calls-and-data)

This question in my opinion should be edited and possibly closed because it is asking for good coverage, which is generally a loaded question but if it has been already upvoted and answered IMHO there already isn't a point of closing it.

- [What are the options for a prepaid SIM card in Germany?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/what-are-the-options-for-a-prepaid-sim-card-in-berlin)

This question is looking for options of cell phone coverage in Berlin, which is likely on topic and doesn't solicit any opinions.

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17298/cell-phone-in-california

This one is wrong on great many levels including asking for cheapest option, which in the US can be many and second recommendations which is non-constructive here as per FAQ.  If one bothered looking at the questions asked and simply asked if the options mentioned in questions like [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/prepaid-gsm-data-provider-for-connecticut-and-nyc) and asked if the options mentioned and those in the related question are available in California it would have been left alone.

Comment: The Berlin one is asking for a list. I thought that would not be allowed here

Comment: @MarcelC. Generally not but in some cases unavoidable as long as it is 90+% definitive.

Comment: I don't understand ?????

Comment: @MarcelC. See http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/799/what-qualifies-as-a-list-question-and-what-doesnt