# Why was this question about free parking closed whereas many other free parking questions are open (and typically upvoted)?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Why was the question [Where can one park one's car for free for a few weeks reasonably close to Seattle (SEA) airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168799/1810) closed whereas there exist many other free parking questions that are open and upvoted such as:

- [Where can you find free parking near the Melbourne Zoo?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/173287/1810)
- [Free street parking in Montreal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/119611/1810)
- [Free parking in downtown Mountain View?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17068/1810)
- [Free street parking options for unlimited time in Bratislava?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/48631/1810)
- [Is there free parking in Springdale, UT, USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49139/1810)
- [Where's the closest free parking for the Canadian side of Niagara Falls?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49177/1810)
- [Any free evening parking in downtown Denver?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17050/1810)
- [What is the closest free street parking to London city center?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/85481/1810)
- [Free street parking in Paris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25676/1810)
- [San Ysidro Pedwest parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/103954/1810)
- [San Ysidro Border Parking Options?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76198/1810)

?

None of the closevoters left any comments, hence this meta question.

---

Update: I saw this meta question [To park for free or not to park for free?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1345/1810) that raised the same issue 8 years ago and the two upvoted answers mentioned that the free parking questions are on-topic. Therefore I don't understand why [Where can one park one's car for free for a few weeks reasonably close to Seattle (SEA) airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168799/1810) was closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129953/discussion-between-rory-alsop-and-franck-dernoncourt).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, a scope of the site is not well defined.

It's similar to the Expatriates. What disappoints me, is the vague assumption that everything that applies to the locals should be made off-topic. If consequently applied, it would lead to the absurd, because most of the questions about local attractions should be closed as off-topic - because they're likely to be visited by locals as well.

On the other hand, business travel is considered on-topic, although everything related to the work should belong to The Workplace.

I think that short-term parking should be on-topic, just like short-term accommodation.